# Boolean expression in Python or a string? Always returns 'True'

Tags: python, boolean-expression

I'm trying to build a Boolean expression, based on (unpredictable) user input. I find that I'm building a string that looks proper, but doesn't work. I've looked at python.org, Google and Stackoverflow and couldn't find what goes wrong here.

Example of the code:

```
    print stringDing
    newVariable = stringDing.replace('False','0')
    print newVariable
    print bool(newVariable)
```

Output from this:

```
    False or False or False
    0 or 0 or 0
    True
```

Yet when the string is pasted into python, python responds as expected:

```
    >>> False or False or False
    False
```

I think I need to build this as a string because the user can add 'OR', 'AND' and brackets, which I would need to fit in at the proper place.

How to proceed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interpreting a non-empty string as `bool` will always evaluate to `True`. I.e.:

```
print bool("False") # True
print bool("0") # True
```

This is, because a str is an iterable object (such as `list`, `set` or `dict`). All iterable objects are considered to be `True`, if they are non-empty. A `str` is an iterable, that iterates over its characters. This is useful, e.g. if you want to test if a string `s` is empty. In such a case you can just write:

```
if s:
  # do something with non-empty string s.
```

However, if you want to **evaluate the expression** that is represented by the string, then call `eval`:

```
print eval("False") # False
print eval("0") # 0
print bool(eval("0")) # False
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander! Somehow I hadn't fount the eval. I tested this, works

Answer (score 0):

If you want to evaluate the way it is evaluated at the python prompt, you can just do `eval(stringDing)`.  If it is a logical expression, it will return a bool.

Answer (score 0):

Using `eval(some_string)` in the wrong context is really dangerous. For example, at the command-line you might want to convert the value of an argument to True or False, as in:

```
sys.argv = ['your_app.py', '--is_true', 'True']
```

But someone could just as easily type:

```
sys.argv = ['your_app.py', '--is_true', 'os.remove("your_app.py")']
```

And. using `eval`, they would delete your application. Instead, I use a dictionary, as in:

```
{'True': True, 'False': False}[some_string]
```

It is much safer, and, as a bonus, throws an error when the wrong input is used.